# I cant't scroll my SingleChildScrollView widget in my flutter application

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I have a column with no fixed number of children inside the SingleChildScrollView, and it assumes the size of all column inside it. But when it gets to the limit of the sreen, I can't scroll inside the widget. What I want is for the  SingleScrollView to have the size defined by all the children inside the column, and I could scroll just the single widget.

Here the code:

```
return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      isScrollControlled: true,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return const FormTask();
                      }).then((value) => setState(() {
                        _data = getTasks(true);
                      }));
                },
                label: const Text("Nova Tarefa"),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.watch_later_outlined),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Próximas Tarefas", style: theme.textTheme.bodySmall),
                const Divider(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: _data,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<CrmTask>> snapshot) {
            List<CrmTask> data = snapshot.data ?? [];
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              if (data.isEmpty) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.error_outline_outlined),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text(
                          "Não há tarefas pendentes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                              fontSize: theme.textTheme.bodySmall!.fontSize),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      // shrinkWrap: true,
                      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: data
                          .map(
                            (e) => Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                              child: Center(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  child: Material(
                                    color: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(5),
                                    ),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(5)),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        showModalBottomSheet(
                                            isScrollControlled: true,
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return FormTask(tarefaId: e.id);
                                            }).then((value) => setState(() {
                                              _data = getTasks(true);
                                            }));
                                      },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA5yL.png)